# Created new column but I am still getting NoMethodError/ undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is the complete error:

```
       Failure/Error: project = Factory.create(:question, :title => "How much does a wood chuck?")
       NoMethodError:
       undefined method `title=' for #<Question:0x007fe38caad1c0>
       # ./spec/integration/creating_questions_spec.rb:15:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I created a new column called 'title' doing this:

```
    rails generate migration AddTitleToQuestions title:string
```

Then I migrated the DB. This is my schema.rb

```
     ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20130714164611) do

      create_table "questions", :force => true do |t|
        t.string   "post"
        t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
        t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
        t.string   "title"
      end
     end
```

In my model:

```
    class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
         attr_accessible :post
    end
```

I tried adding 'title' to my model to see if it fixes it but I still get the same error. Any ideas.

**Fixed it:
I ended up doing a hard reset to a previous commit and creating the new column again. It works now I'm not sure what was wrong before.**

Answer (score 1):

Try running rake db:test:prepare and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Rails uses db/schema.db file as a source of models structure, so reloading it with `rake db:schema:dump` should do the trick.